# What is the proper action, one should take if the construction of some user's name on this site is wrong

Tags: discussion

On stack exchange, different user use different sentences and phrases as user name, and this may be single work, a combination of several words and\or numbers, in English, Arabic, or other. If I passed by some user name that, is opposite to well know fact, or it's against a well documented report, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In general, what a user chooses to use as his display name or put in his profile is up to them. Diamond Moderators can change such elements if it's flagged for their attention, but are not likely to do so unless the content is blatantly inappropriate or likely to cause offense.

If someone chooses to, quite frankly, *lie* in their display name for whatever reason, that's up to them. I would strongly recommend they avoid doing so, as such would basically just discourage anyone from taking their expertise seriously, but that's entirely their choice.